# How to scroll a tableView inside the cell of another tableview?

Tags: uitableview, ios7

I have a survey of questions as a tableview, each cell is a question. Some of the questions require answers from a long list of answers (like a drop down list e.g. 52 states), so I decided to create the answers as a tableview inside cell.contentview.

I can figure out the child tableview's size and call heightForRow to control height of the cell, but if the list is long, it will have a long table "a long cell - looks ugly. Is there a way to allow scrolling the child tableview while limiting the size of it, I can't seem to figure it out? Is it not allowing me because it is a subview of the parent tableview cell?

Comment: Have you thought about a way to not have the outer table view? Maybe having a scroll view with multiple subviews that take up the widths of the screen with tables inside. A table in a table will not work well.

Comment: I did think about it, but I thought I could keep track of my objects as a tableview because of all the delegate methods available, i.e. I would know which question I am working on using the "selectedRow".. Also, based on answers, I need to insert/delete child rows, tableviews do well with these transactions..etc